# Find count of unique pairs between columns for each date

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures

I have a table that holds the location data for each login. Fields are longitude, latitude and logondate.

I want to find the # of unique logins per date for a week, sorted by date.

So, I want my output table to be:

```
# UNIQUE LOGINS | DATE
```

where a unique login is where the (longitude, latitude) pair is common. I don't care about the pairs themselves, just the count.

What would this query look like?

Thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT lng, lat) AS cnt, DATE(`date`) AS `date` FROM log GROUP BY DATE(`date`);
```

More on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07fcc/1/0